# AnyLogic: Set Agents to Nodes on a GIS Map

Tags: maps, gis, nodes, anylogic, agent

I am working within a project team and we want to create kind of a digital twin showing all the logistical streams within a city. We therefore already implemented all the stores, pharmacies, doctors, etc. as individual GIS points. In the next step we want to apply certain agents to the GIS points.

Therefore we tried to create a population of agents which we thought we could later on connect to the correct nodes representing the adress within the GIS map. Thats where our problem occured. We were only able to select one node although we set our population of agents to the amount 10. Is there a trick how to solve the problem or do we have to forget our approach and instead have to consolidate all of the adresses within an excel sheet which we can use as a database for our agents.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: what did you do to connect to that node?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by connect to that node? We implemented all the gis points on the map and when we tried to connect a population of agents to multiple of those gis points via the "in the node"-function we were not abl to select more than 1 gis point although our population of agents was around 10.

Comment: lol you are the one who said that you connected to a node... i'm using your own vocabulary so how can you be confused

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I misunderstood you. We went into the agent properties and then wanted to select all the GIS Points in the "node" field where we wanted our agents to be placed but we were only able to select on gis point at a time

Answer (score 0):

on the node initial location you can use a function that retunrs a GISPoint

On this function you establish the rules you need in order to place the agents randomly accross the nodes or in a way that you want

for example if the function does this::

```
if(randomTrue(0.5)) return gisPoint;
else return gisPoint1;
```

all the agents would be placed randomly on gisPOint or gisPoint1